# Integral of $\frac1{\cos^n x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, problem-solving

Hi guys I have already proven for an assignment that:

$$\int\cos(x)^n dx=\frac{1}{n}\cos(x)^{n−1}\sin(x) + \frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos(x)^{n−2}dx$$

Now we have been asked to calculate $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\cos^4(x)}dx$$ theoretically make $n=-4$, however the expression below will only work for $n\geq2$ right?

Halp please

Comment: That identity only depends on $n$ not being zero, so it will work with $n=-2$ which is what you need.

Comment: If i do that then I keep subtracting -2 on each step and won't  reach zero or stop it just keeps going negative.

Comment: That's not what Matt meant. With $n=-2$ you will find the integral that you seek (with $\cos^{-4}x$) on the *right-hand* side of the identity, in terms of something simpler (with $\cos^{-2} x$) on the left-hand side.

Comment: I see it now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity holds unless integer $n\ne0$

First set $n=-2$

$$\int\cos(x)^{-2} dx=\frac{1}{-2}\cos(x)^{-2−1}\sin(x) + \frac{-2-1}{-2}\int\cos(x)^{-2−2}dx$$

$$\iff\frac32\int\cos(x)^{-4}dx=\int\cos(x)^{-2} dx+\frac12\cos(x)^{-3}\sin(x)$$

Now, $$\int\cos^{-2}x\ dx=\int\sec^2x\ dx=\tan x+K$$

Comment: Ok then what would the point be of having solved all that before to now use a different path to solve that?

Comment: @sasquatch112233, Not sure if I've understood your point. The idea will be to reach $$\int\cos^1x\ dx$$ or $$\int\cos^{-2}x\ dx$$ from ant integer $n$

Comment: its to calculate the definite integral from 0 to (pi/4) of 1/cos(x)^4. I believe I need to use what I already did on the previous step, the integral I had to prove, I gotta write every step can't just get matlab or wolfam to do for me :(

Comment: @sasquatch112233, Have you solved the indefinite integral?

Comment: No that's where I'm stuck, sorry if it's something simple what I'm missing or not seeing, the lack of sleep isn't doing wonders for me.